# Create a double group scatterplot

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create a "double grouped scatterplot" like in the image below, where I would like to portray 20 numerical each time. The data exists already in the corresponding format (example given in the second image below), but some data points are missing (#Null!).

I have thought a long time about the best way to create the diagram I need, but didn't manage to come up with a satisfying solution. Do you have any smart ideas about an easy way to create the diagram?

Cheers,
Mil

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure that this is really answering what you are asking, however I think that the video [Excel 2010 Statistics Chp03 by ExcelisFun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur_C64ifCoU&index=30&list=PLFAD0C5745D4A1F60) starting at about the 36:20 mark may be close to presenting the data the way that you want. I managed to make vertical columns of markers on a chart, by making a data column of 1's and to the left of your "W11" data values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a good challenge. I've done both of the graphs you are looking for, but never on the same graph.

**Setting up data**

First thing you'll need to do is remove the `#NULL!` values from the data and replace them with blanks.

Range B3:F23

[image: remove nulls]

You'll then need to calculate the median and Quartiles

Here are the results (Range A27:F29):

[image: calculate median and quartiles]

With these formulas:

```
75% quartile: =QUARTILE.INC(B4:B23,3)
Median:       =MEDIAN(B4:B23)
25% quartile: =QUARTILE.INC(B4:B23,1)
```

To get the boxes on the graph we'll do stacked columns, with the first column formatted with no fill color

Here are the results (Range A32:F24):

[image: stacked col calc]

Where:

```
"Col Blank" is equal to Quartile 25%
"Col 25-50%" is equal to Median less Quartile 25%
"Col 50%-75% is equal to Quartile 75% less Median
```

Now for the dots we'll need to add the x values (there may be another way to do this, but this is a quick and easy way - Range I4:M23)

[image: x values]

**Now to create the chart**

1. Select Range A32:F34 and insert a stacked column chart.
2. Format the `Col Blank` as no fill and no border
3. Format the other 2 series as light gray fill with 75% transparency and light gray border
4. Edit the Horizontal Axis Labels to include your series titles (W11, W21, etc)

that will give you the boxes, now to add the dots.

1. Add a new series to your chart (through Select Data) and select anything as your Series Name and Series Values (some cell with a number though)
2. Right-click the new series on the chart and select `Change Series Chart Type`
3. Select `Scatter with markers only`
4. Back to the `Select Data` area and edit your new series to look like the following screen shot

[image: xy series set up]

Then repeat that with the other series.

**Final product**

After a little additional formatting we get this:

[image: Final chart]

Comment: That's Good Stuff